# "text-align:center" not working after text change

Tags: html, css

I recently did a simple text change on this website and suddenly the text will not center. I did not touch the CSS at all and cannot figure out what is causing it.

Here is the link:
http://newyork-fashionweek.com/

The text that I am referring to is in the "Tickets" section where it says "BUY".
Help please?

Thank you.

P.S. You can bypass the email signup by just clicking "join" and not entering an email.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Next time post your code. For your problem just remove the padding on the .tixtext span and set display to block.

Comment: Thank you, RafH. I'm not the builder. I just came into this project to edit and noticed the display was not set to block shortly after posting. Next time I will be sure to post code. Best.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to center text inside of a `<span>`. You cannot center inside of an inline element. You can only center inside of a block-level element. Change this to a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`. If you must have an inline element then change the `<div>` display property to `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Add display: block; and remove padding

This should work:

```
.tixtext {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
line-height: 21px;
width: 100px;
display: table-cell;
padding: 4.5px 10px 12.5px 15px;
```

In this case , his cash have a size defined and it and possible serialize this picture paragraph a direction.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.